# Is there any effect of handling service-worker.js in the same service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Let's say my service worker is `sw.js`. If I precache or cache this file using the same service-worker (`sw.js`), is there any effect ?

For example, using [sw-toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox),

```
toolbox.precache(['sw.js']);
toolbox.router.get('/sw.js', toolbox.cacheOnly);
```

and,

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
```

Now, should this service-worker ever update, or will the browser allow a special fetch that checks if the URL is an exact match of the active ServiceWorkerURL and respect the 24 hour compulsory update of service worker and hit the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#service-worker-registration-update:

> update() pings the server for an updated version of this script without consulting caches. This is conceptually the same operation that UA does maximum once per every 24 hours.

Also, from https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#update-algorithm, step 4.8:

> Let response be the result of running fetch using r, forcing a network fetch if cached entry is greater than 1 day old.

Comment: Isn't that the HTTP Cache instead of CacheStorage ? Or does it mean both/anything ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it means any kind of cache.

Answer (score 0):

**NO.**

The request for update does **NOT** go through the service-worker at all.

According to the ServiceWorker Spec -

Point **5.2** in Update Algorithm - https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#update-algorithm

> Set request’s [skip service worker flag](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#skip-service-worker-flag) and request’s [redirect mode](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-redirect-mode) to "error".

And fetch has a https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#skip-service-worker-flag which is

1. **set** only for a [WebSocket connection (Point 2)](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-websocket-establish)
2. **NOT set** or **unset** for all requests that go out from the Document - [HTTP Fetch (Point 3)](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-http-fetch)
3. This flag is **NOT** exposed and it's not something you can use it in your requests.

For the service worker update, this flag is **set** and it doesn't go through the service worker lifecycle event - fetch. Cross check with,

```
toolbox.router.get('/sw.js', function(...args) {
  // never called
  console.log(...args);
  return toolbox.cacheOnly(...args);
});
```

Use this SW code and try refreshing the page, you never get to this function for updating the service worker. This function gets called only when you,

```
fetch('/sw.js')
```

from the Document.